# One Cateogry showing 404 - Subdirectory store

Tags: magento-1.9, category

I have a subdirectory store which is MYURL/demo

I then have categories in there MYURL/demo/shop/category1 MYURL/demo/shop/category2

My initial categories are working fine, worth noting I have upgraded to 1.9.2.2 recently (EDIT: Tried on test environment which is still 1.9.0.1 and I get the same). I try to add a new category, checked the settings, exactly the same as the previous.

It shows up on MYURL/shop which lists the categories, but when I click through to the category I have a 404.

I also have a product inside it, which if I move to another category works fine!

Can anyone suggest how I can debug why this isn't displaying?

EDIT: Did some logging to in Category Helpers to see if an issue with the ID, Active State or Root Category with no issues

Comment: did you rebuild the url rewrites index?

Comment: I did a reindex all and cache clear via SSH if that's what you mean?

Comment: yep. that's what I mean.

Comment: Ah ok well yes that's what I have done, I have no idea where to begin with troubleshooting this!